# Using Pow in C++ MinGW. Works hard coded but not with variables

Tags: c++, variables, pow

This is hopefully a simple linker issue but I've spent hours searching and haven't moved forward in that time. I'm trying to use

```
 #include <cmath>
 double aA = 2;
 double result = pow((double)2.0,(double)aA);
```

I get no error messages and it compiles without issue. But an unrelated grid I'm drawing with openGL doesn't display. If i substitute the aA for 2 then it displays the grid. Like

```
 #include <cmath>
 double aA = 2;
 double result = pow((double)2.0,(double)2);
```

This outputs 4 as expected. The previous example outputs nothing. It's as if the program hangs but there are no errors.

This computation isn't used anywhere and in fact just sits in main (or anywhere else) and the variables are unique and are unused.

I'm using code::blocks and minGW GNU GCC compiler in Windows 7. -g -Wall - WExtra

Rendering with glew + freeglut and everything else works until i use a variable with pow.

I've tried every combination of casting I can think of and I've tried powf with the exact same result. I'm using sqrt and other functions so believe that the inclusion is working. I've also tried math.h but get the same problem.

I have never wished to see an error message from a compiler more so than I do right now.

So 1. Why am I not getting an error when it looks like its stopping the whole program in its tracks?
And 2. What have I missed to get pow() working with variables?

Update : After creating a new project and trying it out I have no issues so there must be something in my setup that's interfering. I'll keep experimenting. Thanks for the quick responses things sure move fast around here!

Update 2:

Very strange.

```
  float aAs = 1.0;
  float amplitudeA = (float)pow((float)2.,(float)aAs);

  char str[50];
  int test = (int) (amplitudeA);
  sprintf (str, "out - %d", test);
  MessageBox(NULL,str,NULL,NULL);
```

This outputs 2 in the message box. Then my grid draws and the program behaves. If i comment out only the message box like so:

```
  float aAs = 1.0;
  float amplitudeA = (float)pow((float)2.,(float)aAs);

  char str[50];
  int test = (int) (amplitudeA);
  sprintf (str, "out - %d", test);
  //MessageBox(NULL,str,NULL,NULL);
```

No drawing of my grid. What could be causing this?

```
  char str[50];
  int test = (int) (1);
  sprintf (str, "out - %d", test);
  MessageBox(NULL,str,NULL,NULL);

  float aAs = 1.0;
  float amplitudeA = (float)pow((float)2.,(float)aAs);
```

Swapping the message box over recreates the issue. No grid drawn. It's as if focus needs to be taken away from the program when I'm using a variable in pow. I'm completely baffled.

Another Update : I temporarily got around it by writing my own simple powerOf function. But now I'm having the same issue with the cos() function.

[image: sigh]
Can anyone tell me if there is something wrong with that image? This issue has to stem from incorrect linking. Is that what you would expect from hovering over coz in code::blocks with gcc?

This a error that occurs only when running through the program with a bad cos call. Interesting that I've been using cos for camera calculations since I started this app with no issue.

```
Error #667: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS: reading 0x00000003-0x00000007 4 byte(s)
# 0 ntdll.dll!RtlImageNtHeader          +0x124c   (0x77ca43d0 <ntdll.dll+0x343d0>)
# 1 ntdll.dll!RtlImageNtHeader          +0x422    (0x77ca35a7 <ntdll.dll+0x335a7>)
# 2 ntdll.dll!RtlImageNtHeader          +0x30d    (0x77ca3492 <ntdll.dll+0x33492>)
# 3 KERNEL32.dll!HeapFree               +0x13     (0x775e14dd <KERNEL32.dll+0x114dd>)
# 4 atioglxx.dll!atiPPHSN               +0x11afaa (0x66538f3b <atioglxx.dll+0xeb8f3b>)
# 5 atioglxx.dll!DrvSwapBuffers         +0x33fb   (0x6569b9cc <atioglxx.dll+0x1b9cc>)
# 6 atioglxx.dll!DrvSwapBuffers         +0x3cad   (0x6569c27e <atioglxx.dll+0x1c27e>)
# 7 atioglxx.dll!DrvSwapBuffers         +0x7c57   (0x656a0228 <atioglxx.dll+0x20228>)
# 8 atioglxx.dll!DrvSwapBuffers         +0x12c    (0x656986fd <atioglxx.dll+0x186fd>)
# 9 atioglxx.dll!DrvValidateVersion     +0x28     (0x65697c19 <atioglxx.dll+0x17c19>)
#10 OPENGL32.dll!wglSwapMultipleBuffers +0xc5d    (0x66c8af0b <OPENGL32.dll+0x3af0b>)
#11 OPENGL32.dll!wglSwapMultipleBuffers +0xe45    (0x66c8b0f3 <OPENGL32.dll+0x3b0f3>)
Note: @0:00:05.233 in thread 3136
Note: instruction: mov    0x04(%ecx) -> %ecx
```

Comment: there's no reason it should no works. Are you sure about it?what about result, is it wrong?

Comment: Working with me with the same configuration... Can you print the result ?

Comment: Which GCC / MinGW versions are you using exactly?

Comment: Can you post clearly the code that "works" and the one that doesn't?

Comment: MinGW is the latest from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/

Comment: When changes in code cause random changes in unrelated behaviour, it's usually a sign of memory corruption (or other UB) somewhere in the program (not necessarily at either of the places where you change code or the error manifests).

Comment: DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized    <Is this warning related? It has started showing up either I didn't see it before or I didn't have the correct switches on earlier.

Comment: And that error is gone again after restarting codeblocks. I'm getting really erratic behavior now. Time to clean installs of everything.

Comment: Or look for memory corruption. Try Valgrind

Comment: Ok on windows but grabbed Dr Memory. Ran it once with a cos call and once without. it found 12,000 errors, mostly invalid heap arguments and leaks. Not too surprising but that could be causing me trouble. The one that wouldn't run however did have an extra error. I'll paste it into the main question

Comment: I've seen cases where `pow()` with constant arguments is evaluated at compile time, but with variable arguments the compiler generates an actual function call that isn't resolved unless you link with `-lm`. That doesn't seem to be the case here, but it was my first thought when I read the title.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. There was an uninitialized variable that was sitting at the bottom of the vertex buffer object I was using to draw the grid. For whatever reason feeding a variable to one of the math functions caused unexpected results in this buffer object.

Thanks to Angew an Kos for pointing me towards memory.